# AWS CodeArtifact, NuGet and Linux

Tags: nuget, aws-codeartifact

wondering if anybody has worked with AWS CodeArtifact on Linux.

Per Method #1, I've installed the CodeArtifact Credential provider per this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/nuget-cli.html#nuget-configure-cli), which seemed to have no effect.

Per Method #2, I installed NuGet (and Mono) and tried using the `aws codeartifact login` command, but get a "nuget was not found" message even though I can execute nuget from the shell.

Before I bang my head against any further walls, I'm wondering if this is a Windows-only type of implementation from AWS.  Getting answers from them is always difficult, so I was hoping somebody around here has already walked this minefield.

THanks

Comment: have you been able to find the solution for this? I'm running in the exact same error and not finding any fix for it.

Comment: Sorry, I gave up, ended up using the package management in our Gitlab server